# Using humane.js with aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to use [humane.js](http://wavded.github.io/humane-js/) with [aurelia](http://aurelia.io) however I'm running in a problem.

It appears humane.js adds an element to the DOM when it's created and so far the only way I've found to do it is to force it like this....

```
showMessage(message) {
    this.notify = humane.create();
    this.notify.log(message);
}
```

However this creates a new instance of humane every time showMessage() is called. This breaks the queue as each one is rendered separately.

I've tried putting the `create()` in the `activate()` method of the view model but that doesn't seem to work either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solved the problem, I've created a custom element for humane that is then included in app.html in the same way loading-indicator is in the skeleton app.

```
import humane from 'humane-js';
import 'humane-js/themes/original.css!';
import {inject, noView} from 'aurelia-framework';
import { EventAggregator } from 'aurelia-event-aggregator';
import { ApiStatus } from 'resources/messages';

@noView
@inject(EventAggregator)
export class StatusIndicator {

  constructor(ea) {
    this.ea = ea;
    ea.subscribe(ApiStatus, msg => this.showMessage(msg.apistatus));
  }

  attached() {
    this.humane = humane.create();
  }

  showMessage(message) {
    this.humane.log(message);
  }
}
```

The important part was the `attached()` this allows the setup of humane to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately for Aurelia, Humane will attach itself to the DOM automatically as a child of body, which Aurelia then replaces.

There is a really, really, simple fix for this:

Change your:

```
<body aurelia-app="main">
```

To this:

```
<body><div aurelia-app="main">
```

This way, Aurelia doesn't replace the div which is in body, you don't need to worry about attached() or where the import appears in your code, and humane works perfectly.

I have raised a humane github issue for this. https://github.com/wavded/humane-js/issues/69

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I am using humane.js with Aurelia:

1) I load the CSS in the app index.html.

2) In each view model that requires humane, I import humane

import humane from 'humane-js/humane';

I do NOT inject human into the view model.

3) I show notifications like this:

humane.log('Error:, { addnCls: 'humane-libnotify-error' });

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it doesn't render the notification. I wonder if I build a custom element with no view like the loader.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work either. It just isn't doing the setup part.